# ¿Como le aplico filtro a un count de SQL Server? Esto mientras hago un inner Join

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssms, sql-server-management

Tengo una tabla llamada Employee y otra Prestamos, en Employee no es mas que el nombre de los empleados y otros datos, en Prestamos tomo los ID de la tabla Employee y ahí hago un registro de herramientas que tienen prestadas, habiendo dos estatus: "Entregada" y "En Préstamo". Tengo este Select en donde extraigo sus ID de Empleado, sus nombres con un Concatenado, y me hace un conteo de los prestamos, pero en este caso me trae todos los prestamos que tiene, pero yo solo quiero los que están en activo los que están en = "En Préstamo" o != "Entregada" (diferente a "Entregada"), el problema de la consulta actualmente es que me trae tanto los que están en "En Préstamo" como los de "Entregada", lo cual no debería ser así, ya que si alguien paso de tener 4 prestamos de herramienta y ahora tiene 3, mi consulta hace que se le vean los 4 aun. (Los dos likes que tiene solo son para usarlos ya en el programa en C#)

```
select E.Employee as Empleado, E.First_Name + ' ' + E.Last_Name as 'Nombre Completo', (COUNT(idempleado)) as 'Cantidad de Herramienta Otorgadas' 
                from Prestamos as P
                Join Employee as E on Cast(P.IdEmpleado as varchar(10)) = E.Employee 
                Where  P.Estatus != 'Entregada' and FechaEntrega is not null and CONCAT(E.First_Name, ' ', E.Last_Name) like '%%' or Employee like '%%'  
                Group by E.Employee, E.First_Name, E.Last_Name 
                order by E.Employee desc
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: O sea... prestaste algo... lo devolvio.. y eso, como queda registrado en la tabla?? porque sql no sabe las reglas de tu negocio.. de alguna forma, hay que modelar eso...

Comment: Sip, se hace el cambio en la tabla, digo si hago la consulta sin inner join haciéndolo directo algo como:
````
select COUNT(IdEmpleado) from prestamos where Estatus != 'Entregada' and IdEmpleado= 603;
````

Me hace el conteo correctamente

Comment: tendriamos que ver un ejemplo mas claro entre las dos tablas, para poder probar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tu consulta ya tiene ese filtro, el problema es que te falta agrupar con paréntesis el filtro de empleados. Eso hace que te regrese todos los datos porque `Employee like '%%'` siempre será verdadero y eso va a generar que el `WHERE` resulte verdadero porque está precedido de un `OR`.

Eso se debe a [la precedencia de operadores](https://learn.microsoft.com/es-es/sql/t-sql/language-elements/operator-precedence-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) en SQL que hace que primero se evaluen los `AND` y después los `OR`. Para evitar ese problema, solo tienes que agregar paréntesis para agrupar las condiciones del empleado.

```
select E.Employee as Empleado, 
       E.First_Name + ' ' + E.Last_Name as 'Nombre Completo', 
       (COUNT(idempleado)) as 'Cantidad de Herramienta Otorgadas' 
 from Prestamos as P
 Join Employee as E on Cast(P.IdEmpleado as varchar(10)) = E.Employee 
 WHERE  P.Estatus != 'Entregada' 
 AND    FechaEntrega is not null 
 AND    (CONCAT(E.First_Name, ' ', E.Last_Name) LIKE '%%' OR Employee LIKE '%%')  
 GROUP BY E.Employee,
          E.First_Name,
          E.Last_Name 
 ORDER BY E.Employee DESC;
```

Comment: Oh muchas gracias, ya quedo ya me muestra solo los registros en donde es diferente a Entregada, no me había percatado de la prioridad en mi where.